# Linq Contains method for a object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object `User` and it is the following class:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `IEnumerable<User>`

I want to find out if one specific user exists in `IEnumerable<User>`, comparing the user by it's ID.

An example:

```
IList<User> users = GetUsers();     // 1, 2, 3
IEnumerable<User> list = GetList(); // 2, 5, 8

// this doesn't work
list.Contains(users[0].ID);         // false
list.Contains(users[1].ID);         // true !
list.Contains(users[2].ID);         // false
```

How can I do it? And what is the fastest way to retrieve this boolean, is it Contains?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to check a `User`, not an `int`.  [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) will work well for this:

```
// this does work
list.Any(user => user.ID == users[0].ID);         // false
list.Any(user => user.ID == users[1].ID);         // true !
list.Any(user => user.ID == users[2].ID);         // false
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list.Any(u => u.ID == thing)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid the lambda expression, and think you may need to compare `User` objects by ID in other parts of your code, consider writing a comparer as follows.

```
class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<User>.Equals(User lhs, User rhs)
    {
        return lhs.ID == rhs.ID;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<User>.GetHashCode(User user)
    {
        return user.ID;  // assumes all IDs are unique.
    }
}
```

Then your list query looks like the following.

```
IEnumerable<User> list = GetList();
IEqualityComparer<User> userComparer = new UserEqualityComparer();

list.Contains(users[0], userComparer);
list.Contains(users[1], userComparer);
// etc...
```

To answer your question related to speed of retrieval, `Contains` is the fastest way if you don't know how the `User` objects are ordered in your collection.  If they were sorted by ID and stored in a `List<User>` object, you could use the `List<User>.BinarySearch()` method with an appropriate implementation of `IComparer<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `var check = list.Where(lu => lu.ID == users[0].ID)` and then test for `check.Count() == 1`
2. `var check = list.FirstOrDefault(lu => lu.ID == users[0].ID)` and then test for `check != null`.
3. `list.Any(user => user.ID == users[1].ID);`