# Determine if LINQ Enumerable contains object based on a condition?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<Project>`

I want to know if this list has any element `Project.ID == someID`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If the enumerable has *Any* item that will satisfy a predicate. Hmmmm....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293618/linq-contains-method-for-a-object?rq=1

Comment: @Milo Correction: I psssssst you off >:|

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you want to use the `Any` method ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)).

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects = SomeMethodReturningProjects();
if(projects.Any(p => p.ID == someID))
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: +1 because it's the only answer to include a link.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method.

```
var hasAny = projectList.Any(proj => proj.ID == someID);
```

Or, if you want to get that record, you can use [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
var matchedProject = projectList.FirstOrDefault(proj => proj.ID == someID);
```

This will return `null` if it finds nothing that matches, but will pull the whole object if it does find it.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
projects.Any(p => p.ID == someID)
```

returns true (a boolean) if the predicate matched for any element.

Comment: Please include relevant reference links.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the `Any` extension method:

```
list.Any(p => p.ID == someID);
```